# How can I change the \pagenumbering without resetting the page count?

Tags: page-numbering

I want to start the page numbers with 1 on my table of contents, but I do not want to show page numbers.

I can do this with `\pagenumbering{gobble}`.

After the toc, I want to show the numbers with arabic numerals but I do **not** want to reset the page count. How can I do this?

I have a book on latex that tells me to set the page counter to some other value if I want to start with another value, like so:

```
\setcounter{page}{some_number_here}
```

But this doesn't work, because the counter, that holds the value to which I want to set the page counter is the page counter itself, which just got reset to 1.

How can I start showing page numbers without resetting their value?

minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
There is no page number on this page, great!
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{A}
This should not be the first page, 
just the first page that displays the numbers.
In this example, this should be page 2
\clearpage
\section{B}
text
\clearpage
\section{C}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}` at the right place should do

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hiding the page number is best done with page styles. You'll have big problems with `hyperref` if you use `\pagenumbering{gobble}`. What document class are you using?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thank you. You already answered my question, please post it as an answer. I'm rather new here and agree and understand that an MWE is necessary, so I added it to my question. Is that how an MWE should look like? Should I include what software I use to compile it? Also greetings to Black Forest, *if only I had a teacher who taught me tex back in the day when I was in school...*

Comment: @null: Alright ... but egreg is right: Hidding/displaying should be done with `\pagestyle`, not with `gobble`

Comment: @egreg the article class. Please also see the MWE in my edit. Is hyperref the only concern? I am certain that I do not want to use hyperrefs in this document. I only found pagenumbering and how it resets the page count. If there's a duplicate question that does this with page styles please flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hidding/displaying page numbers/headers/footers should be done with page styles, such as `empty` or `plain` (or more sophisticated ones).

If `article` class is used, then no explicit redefinition of `\thepage` to `\arabic{page}` is necessary, but in the case of `book` and `\frontmatter`, the ToC would be displayed with roman figures, so this redefinition might be necessary.

`\pagenumbering{...}` always resets the page counter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}  % No page numbers/headers/footers
\tableofcontents
There is no page number on this page, great!
\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain} % restore the plain style
%\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}  % Setting the page output to arabic   -- not necessary, unless `book` class and `\frontmatter` is used.

\section{A}
This should not be the first page, 
just the first page that displays the numbers.
In this example, this should be page 2
\clearpage
\section{B}
text
\clearpage
\section{C}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's no need to redefine `\thepage`

Comment: @egreg: Right... I confused it with the case when roman/Roman figures were used for the ToC.

Comment: I was a little worried already that `\pagenumbering{gobble}` which I found online isn't included in the big LaTex book I have. `\pagestyle` seems to be a very clean and standard way to achieve my goal.